# Matlab function to isolate a variable in an equation

Tags: matlab, equation

I have been searching a function to do “subjecting” in Matlab. I'm not sure whether it is called as subjecting or by some other name. Let me explain the functionality.

Let's say I have an expression like this.

```
syms x, y,z;
y = 2*x^2 - 2*z + 1;
```

I want a function to get the `x` to one side and other variables to the other side.
ie.

```
x = ((y + 2*z - 1)/ 2 )^0.5
```

Is there any functions or built in Matlab command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the documentation of the MATLAB math toolbox at all? It's right there. The function is "solve". Read the documentation here: [solve documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html).

Comment: Yeah.. I got that after posting the question, BTW I'm trying that. Thanks a lot.. :D